# Flagging a comment to change its body?

Tags: 7, comments

Does anyone know if there is a way to include a button (or just a basic link) next to each comment that is used by admins only and when clicked changes the body of the comment to something like "This comment is inappropriate, please read the blahblahblah"?
I tried with [Flag](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag) + [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) but failed to make any changes to the comment body whatsoever.
Any ideas?

Comment: create a comment flag that only admins can see then use jQuery to check if the flag is flag class is there, if it is, then you change the comment body to whatever you like.

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I did. I just added two more functionalities - one that returns the comment to the original state when you unflag it and another one that displays the original comment if the logged in user is administrator.